# HTML Not showing decimals from mysql db in Laravel Blade

Tags: html, mysql, laravel-5, decimal

In my mysql db I manage table's column to keep product prices.like $200.00 or $200.50 (only two points). When it comes to html I catch it like this from blade view.

```
<p class="excerpt col-md-6 col-md-offset-5 alert alert-danger">Price per Instance : AUD ${{$product->product_price}}</p>
```

Problem is, $200.00 it is not showing .00 and when $200.50 it is 200.5 and $200.51 or any two point it gives $200.50999450684 something like this. What should I do

And also please let me know how to save number with two decimal point in html to mysql db

Thanks....

**Update 01:** 
my table structure

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure to set your produce price column in MySQL to `DECIMAL(5,2)` for prices between $0 to $999.99. If it's not, run

`ALTER TABLE #PRODUCTTABLENAME MODIFY COLUMN #PRODUCTPRICECOLUMNNAME DECIMAL(5,2)`

replacing `#PRODUCTTABLENAME` with your table's name and `#PRODUCTPRICECOLUMNNAME` with your column's name

Comment: It's ok. my db holds decimal. but problem is those decimals not shows in html

Comment: That should be possible unless the PHP framework you are using is altering them on the fly as integers... Can you describe more about the project this page is part for?

Comment: PHP Version 5.5.9. here what happen is it eliminates zeros & if decimal is .23 like this, it shows more decimal points

Comment: Can you provide your database table structure and types?

Comment: Edit `product_price` to be `DECIMAL(5, 2)` as `FLOAT(5, 2)` can take away your zeros

Comment: wow! it woks. !! thanks a lot. plz say in one line how to save my price. html textfiled, how should be it looks like

Comment: If it did work, please mark my answer as correct. In addition, what do you mean how to save your price in html textfiled?

Comment: if I add product price as 100, will it save 100.00. and if I add 100.20,is it save in table in the save format (100.20) I didn't try this.I just asked !